# Other alternatives make rand.nextDouble() beetwen -1 and 1

Tags: java, random

This easy program program computes an estimate of pi by simulating dart throws onto a square.

**Сonditions:** Generate a random floating-point number and transform it so that it is between -1 and 1.
Store in x. Repeat for y. Check that (x, y) is in the unit circle, that is, the distance between (0, 0) and (x, y) is <= 1.

After this, need to find the `ratio hits / tries` is approximately the same as the ratio `circle area / square area = pi / 4`. (square is 1 per 1).

**Code:**

```
public class MonteCarlo {
    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        System.out.println("Number of tries");
        Random generator = new Random(42);
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        int tries = in.nextInt();

        int hits = 0;
        double x, y;
        for (int i = 1; i <= tries; i++)
        {
            // Generate two random numbers between -1 and 1            
            int plusOrMinus = generator.nextInt(1000);
            if (plusOrMinus > 500) x = generator.nextDouble();                
            else x = -generator.nextDouble();

            plusOrMinus = generator.nextInt(10000);
            if (plusOrMinus > 5000) y = generator.nextDouble(); 
            else y = -generator.nextDouble();             

            if (Math.sqrt((x * x) + (y * y)) <= 1) // Check whether the point lies in the unit circle
            {
                hits++;
            }
        }

        double piEstimate = 4.0 * hits / tries;
        System.out.println("Estimate for pi: " + piEstimate);
    }
}
```

**Testing output:**

```
  Actual output            Expected output
  -----------------------------------------------
  Number of tries          Number of tries
  1000                     1000
- Estimate for pi: 3.176   Estimate for pi: 3.312

  Actual output               Expected output
  -----------------------------------------------------
  Number of tries             Number of tries
  1000000                     1000000
- Estimate for pi: 3.141912   Estimate for pi: 3.143472
```

Maybe, does exist other approaches to find this solution?
Any suggestions.

Comment: From your Testing Output your program seems to have done a better job of estimating pi (3.141592) than expected. I'd class that as a good thing (although I expect thats just coincidence, it is random after all, a different seed for Random will probably give a different and potentially worse result)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For generating the random double between -1 and 1, try:

```
generator.nextDouble() * 2 - 1
```

BTW: If you keep initializing your random with a static seed, you'll always get the same result. Otherwise, if you are concerned that your result is not good enough, keep in mind that the Monte Carlo is only an approximation. After all, it's based on random numbers, so the result *will* vary from the sample solution ;-)

Comment: @winSharp93 Can you clarify some point? Pseudocode of method: Read a word => Repeat word.length() times => Pick a random position i in the word, but not the last position => `Pick a random position j > i in the word(this point!!)` => Swap the letters at positions j and i => Print the word. I stuck.

Answer (score 1):

A generalized solution to turn a Uniform(0,1) into a Uniform(a,b) (where a < b) is

```
(b - a) * generator.nextDouble() + a
```

As @winSharp93 pointed out, you should expect variation but you can quantify the margin of error as a statistical confidence interval.  If you calculate

```
halfWidth = 1.96 * Math.sqrt(piEstimate * (4.0 - piEstimate) / tries);
```

then the actual value of pi should fall between `piEstimate - halfWidth` and `piEstimate + halfWidth` 95% of the time.  You can see from the `halfWidth` calculation that the range containing pi will shrink (but not linearly) as the number of `tries` is increased.  You can adjust the confidence level from 95% to other values by replacing 1.96 with an alternative scale value out of a Standard Normal table.